# Highcharts wind direction

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make a wind direction gauge, with live data.
Need to convert the wind angle in degrees to NNW, NW etc ,i made a function for that.
The problem is that the labels are skewed in highcharts.  (not on 90, 180 etc.)

Here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CjAWpFHJ

Here is the picture: http://postimage.org/image/c17tlf78l/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using tickPixelInterval, while should be tickInterval, take a look at live example: http://jsbin.com/oyudan/19/edit

I mean of course this line:

```
yAxis: {
    ....
    tickInterval: 22.5,
}
```

You have also set labels.step = 2, so not labels are rendered, in your code:

```
yAxis: {
   ....
   labels: {
        step: 2
   }
}
```

Remove that line if you need all labels.